# Arithmetic operation fails on AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm doing an app in iOS Swift with Parse. I need to increment 1 every time a product is viewed. Following is my code to do that:

```
var prodQuery = PFQuery(className: "prodDet")
        let id = prodId[currprod] as String
        prodQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:id)

        prodQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                for object in objects {

                    var key1: Int = object["key1Total"]! as Int
                    var key1New: Int = key1 + 1

                    object["key1Total"] = key1New

                }
            }
        }
```

The above code gives error "@lvalue$T5 is not identical to AnyObject...". Is anything wrong the way I'm dealing with AnyObject object here; How do we do arithmatic calculation on Parse AnyObjects?

Could somebody please shed some light?

Comment: At what line is the error occuring? Is `object` a *mutable* dictionary?

Comment: The error occurs at this line: object["key1Total"] = key1New. I haven't defined any type for object as you can see here: ... for object in objects { ...

Comment: The problem is most likely that you can't assign an `Int` to a dictionary. Try converting it to `NSNumber` for example.

Comment: Also, although this is not an exact answer to your question, you could use `incrementKey` in this scenario: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/increment-operators/

Comment: @imas145 I did try with NSNumber  but it won't work either. Infact, it fails on this line itself: var key1New: NSNumber = key1 + 1 with error message "Cannot invoke + with an arguement list of type '(@lvalue NSNumber ...."

Comment: If I remember correctly, numbers in Parse are stored as `NSNumber`s anyway, so why not use them directly? `let key1: NSNumber = object["key1Total"] as! NSNumber
            let key1New: NSNumber = NSNumber(integer: key1.integerValue + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out, seems like I should cast the object as PFObject and use object.setValue. The following is the working code:

```
    var prodQuery = PFQuery(className: "prodDet")
let id = prodId[currprod] as String
prodQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:id)

prodQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects as [PFObject] {
                var keyVal = object["key1Total"]! as Int
                var keyNew = keyVal + 1

                object.setValue(keyNew, forKey: "key1Total")

                object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (success) {
                            //
                        } else {
                            //
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                //
                } else {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}